# After passing javascript array to servlet, how do I edit?

Tags: javascript, java

I have javascript array that I've passed to java. This is an array of user input data. I want this list of user input data to be editable, so first will the javascript array be editable with this code for the array?

```
form.addEventListener('submit', collectData, false);

function collectData(e) {
    var userSites = [];
    var cache = document.getElementById('cache');
    var z = 0;
    while (z < max_fields) {
        z++;
        var data = inputs[z].val();
        userSites.push(data);
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    cache.value = userSites;
}
```

I want the user to be able to go back and edit the list later if they so choose and then for the array to update when this happens. I don't know much about javascript, but I know a lot about java. So in java I know that an array list would be better for this, but is that something that works in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript are very modifiable, unlike Java. JavaScript arrays are not a fixed length, and items can be added and removed without any issues.

Slightly unrelated, but something I noticed in your example; JavaScript arrays are 0-indexed, like Java, but in your while loop, you are incrementing z before it ever gets a chance to parse the 0-th element. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: Nope, I didn't mean to do that. Thanks for catching that.